# Is Touch ID "Try Again" alert view's title customizable?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, touch-id, lacontext

I've seen that the first time the Touch ID dialog is displayed, the name of the app is shown by default, and that the subtitle can be set as `localizedReason`. What about setting a completely custom String as title? Is it possible to change the "Try Again" title that is shown when you fail a Touch ID attempt?

Comment: I'm afraid that you can't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot. These OS dialogs are very limited in what you can customize.